# Spark: Split StructType column to multiple columns without using the ".*" star operator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `StructType` column in my Spark DataFrame that I want to split into multiple columns.

```
case class Struct(FIELD_1: Int, FIELD_2: Int, FIELD_3: Int)

val df = Seq(
    (Struct(1,2,3), 2),
    (Struct(4,5,6), 3)
).toDF("col0", "col1")

df.show()
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col0: struct<FIELD_1: int, 
// FIELD_2: int ... 1 more field>, col1: int]
// +---------+----+
// |     col0|col1|
// +---------+----+
// |[1, 2, 3]|   2|
// |[4, 5, 6]|   3|
// +---------+----+
```

One way to split it to its constituent components is to use the `.*` operator. Simply:

```
df.select("col0.*", "col1").show()
// +-------+-------+-------+----+
// |FIELD_1|FIELD_2|FIELD_3|col1|
// +-------+-------+-------+----+
// |      1|      2|      3|   2|
// |      4|      5|      6|   3|
// +-------+-------+-------+----+
```

However, if I would want to apply some UDF `myUDF` on the column first that also returns a struct, it becomes inconvenient to use the `.*` method. Is there a `flattenStruct`-esque method or function that allows me to do this?

```
df.select(flattenStruct(myUDF($"col0")), "col1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first apply the UDF in first DF and then select using * in next select?
`df.select(myUDF($"col0").as("col0"), "col1").select($"col0.*", "col1")`

Comment: Yes that's possible but I am wondering if there is a more elegant method that doesn't require 2 `select`s.

Comment: Didn't find any function available, one way out is to get the schema and iterate through to get the column names

'df.schema.filter(_.name == "col0").flatMap(r => 
                             r.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields.map(_.name))
                       .map(c => "col0."+c)'